# What to do with review of an answer in the formatting sandbox?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

What should we do when reviewing an answer in the Formatting Sandbox question, like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/39771)?

I understand the purpose of the formatting sandbox and I think we shouldn't be too harsh when coming to reviewing such stuff. It is a sandbox and if I am correct those posts will be eventually deleted, but are we actually breaking some analysis tools by clicking *Looks okay*? Or should we delete or recommend deletion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just mark it as *Looks Okay*.

Such posts are fit for the sandbox and can just be waved on. It won't affect analysis tools. If such posts ever ended up as a review audit (as unlikely though that may be), it'll be easy enough to remove them from consideration again.